# How to expose Swift code (iOS application) to be run from Wordpress admin panel like php server code

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, swift, web-applications

I need to daily update a Wordpress backed website pages based on a text input I get via email. So I wrote an iOS app that parses the input text, based on some rules generates HTML page and with some googling I prepared a php code that inserts my updated pages directly into the Wordpress MySQL database and also updates other table so the site menus reflects the newest changes. So far so good.

I am now looking into ways how to automate this workflow further so that I don't have to copy the input text into my iOS app and run the website update every single day. I am seeking a way how to expose the Swift code I have written directly to the Wordpress admin panel, so the website administrator can update the site on his leveraging the Swift code I have already done.

Comment: So you want swift code that was written in a text box on the web to be downloaded and invoked inside of your app?

Comment: No. I have a Swift based app and want to expose the inputs and outputs of the app to the web/MySQL environment. I am looking for a way how can I reuse my code so that the web administrator can launch it from the wordpress admin panel. The clean solution is obviously to rewrite my (Swift) code logic into PHP and include it in the wordpress admin, but I am just checking if anybody has a better idea how to avoid the PHP coding, as I would have to hire a PHP developer.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to write the code in both places. One solution could be to write the code once in Javascript for use online and use Apple's JavascriptCore framework to invoke that same code in your swift app. However, I can't think of a way to get the swift code you've already written to function on another platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to want to write this in PHP or some other language that can run on the Web server and directly access the MySQL database.  I suppose you could make a Cocoa Application to run on a Mac to do this and repurpose your Swift code, but I'm gonna bet your Web server isn't running on a Mac.

Take a look at these:

[Handling Forms in PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

[Connecting to MySQL from PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

[PHP Basics](http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/u/php_basics_tab.htm)

Comment: Correct. My server is running on Linux, so no luck. I was even thinking about adjusting the Swift code to run on a Mac 'server' so the Linux/Wordpress site can talk to it online, but that would require additional Mac hardware to be supported.